# How can I look inside an AppleScript “whose” clause to optimize resolving a script object specifier?

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

The documentation for `-[NSObject scriptingValueForSpecifier:]` says:

> You can override this method to customize the evaluation of object specifiers…

I want to do this to make AppleScript lookups in my app more efficient. There are certain types of `whose` tests where I could do a hash lookup instead of having AppleScript ask for every single object and then query their properties one-by-one. The problem is that if I receive a `NSWhoseSpecifier`, I can get its `test`, which is a `NSSpecifierTest`, but there doesn’t seem to be a way to look inside the `NSSpecifierTest` to figure out the property being tested. Everything but the initializers and the `-isTrue` method are private.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a distinction. If you merely want to customize the values returned by a whose clause — in the sense of fine-tuning results — then you would override `scriptingValueForSpecifier` for the object in question. For example, say you have an object called 'box' that has a property called 'color,' and you want a statement like `every box whose color is blue` to also return boxes whose color is 'aqua,' 'teal,' or 'navy' (which are all shades of blue), then you would override `scriptingValueForSpecifier` to implement that.

However, if your goal is to make a more efficient form of whose test, you're probably going to have to implement appropriate methods from the `NSScriptingComparisonMethods` protocol. These are the routines that AppleScript uses to evaluate scripting object comparisons through `NSSpecifierTest` (which is what `NSWhoseSpecifier`) relies on). Again, you'd override these methods on your object(s) to provide different methods for doing evaluations.

As a last resort, you might try subclassing `NSWhoseSpecifier` or `NSSpecifierTest`, with the understanding that these are opaque classes for which Apple discourages subclassing. I'm not entirely certain *how* you would implement those subclasses; you'd probably have to register your subclass with `NSScriptSuiteRegistry` commands.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don’t think `NSScriptingComparisonMethods` helps here because it works at the level of individual objects. The goal is not to make 100K comparisons against `blue` faster, but to do one lookup to find the box that’s blue. So I think I need to override `-scriptingValueForSpecifier:`, but I run into the problem not being able to see inside the specifier. My understanding is that `NSScriptSuiteRegistry` doesn’t let you register for those types of classes, but of course I’d love to be proven wrong.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'look inside' the specifier. If you override `scriptingValueForSpecifier:`, you will receive an instance of `NSScriptObjectSpecifier`, and you can use the methods and properties of that class to see whatever you want to see about the specifier. Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it lets you access the `NSWhoseSpecifier` which has no useful methods. There’s a tree of objects in there that record which properties are being compared against what, but you can’t see any of that because there are no public methods. So I guess the answer is what I posted separately, which is to walk the underlying `AEDesc` that corresponds to the opaque objects.

Comment: `NSWhoseSpecifier` inherits from `NSScriptObjectSpecifier`, which inherits from `NSObject`, both of which have a number of useful methods. What data in particular are you trying to suss out?

Comment: The details of which property is being compared, using which operator, against which value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it will be possible to override `-scriptingValueForSpecifier:` and then ask the `NSScriptObjectSpecifier` for its `descriptor`. This produces an `NSAppleEventDescriptor` that has the needed information, but it has to be interpreted manually.

Comment: And I suppose you found this https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/svn/300/tree/branches/OmniGroup_OmniFoundation/bibdesk_vendorsrc/OmniGroup/OmniFoundation/OpenStepExtensions.subproj/NSObjectSpecifier-OFFixes.m Unclear to me but Omni frameworks have tackled most of this stuff so might be useful

Comment: Hadn’t seen that, thanks. It looks like this is using private API to get the same information I can already get using the `-descriptor` method (which seems to work now). So I’ll just do that. Thought about using posing to replace `NSSpecifierTest` with more useful versions, but I don’t think that works with the modern runtime.